# Tester class doesn't think my ArrayList is an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create an ArrayList of type Item in my Store class and then test it in another class called StoreTester. I keep getting the error: The method get() is undefined for the type Store. So Java thinks my tester object of type Store is not an ArrayList even though I tried to make it so. 
My Store class constructor:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Store
{

  private ArrayList<Item> blockbuster;

  public Store(){
    blockbuster = new ArrayList<Item>();
  }

  public void addItem(Item i){
    blockbuster.add(i);
  }
}
```

This is my StoreTester class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StoreTester{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Store videostore = new Store();

System.out.print(videostore.toString());
System.out.print(videostore.get(0));
}
}
```

For some reason videostore.toString() works fine and prints out the list of objects I've added to it. Here is the method toString I wrote in my Store class:

```
public String toString(){
    String item = "Items in store: " + "\n";
    for(int j = 0; j < blockbuster.size(); j++){
      item = item + blockbuster.get(j).getTitle() + "\n";
    }
    return item;
  }
```

but as soon as I try to get() a specific object at an index or even use videostore.size(), i get the: method undefined error. Hopefully it is just a syntax error or something simple I've overlooked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `videostore` is a `Store` not an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `Store` does not have a method `get`

It can be implemented in `Store` as

```
public Item get (int index) {

    // check for null, then

    return blockbuster.get(index);
}
```

`Store` has-a `ArrayList` it is not `Store` is-a `ArrayList`

As @ElliottFrisch also mentions, you will need to implement a `size` method as well

```
public int size () {

    // check for null, then

    return blockbuster.size();
}
```

Comment: OP will also need a `size()` method (I would think).

Comment: Thanks guys for ur help. Like Wombat mentioned, my mentality was that Store was an ArrayList, and not that it was holding one that i could use.

Comment: OP should also use proper JUnit tests.  Getters are a code smell and should apply Tell Don't Ask instead.   https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask

Comment: @MartinSpamer I agree with your message, but I feel in this case the OP should learn to walk first.

Comment: @cavermendes If this answer addresses your problem please consider to upvote and/or accept